# No se suben las imágenes al directorio en wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

alguno sabría decirme cómo se pueden subir imagenes dentro del directorio de wordpress. Tengo el problema que cuándo utilizo el método upload, este me reconoce la url dónde va a subirse la imagen, pero cuándo realizo el insert, la imagen no se sube al directorio pero si me aparecen los datos en la base de datos.

Este es mí código:

```
$data = '';
if ( empty( $data['id'] ) ) {
    $data = $param->get_params();
    $filename = $data['file'];
    // Check the type of file. We'll use this as the 'post_mime_type'.
    $filetype = wp_check_filetype( basename( $filename ), null );
    // Get the path to the upload directory.
    $wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();

    $media = wp_insert_attachment(array(
                'guid'           => $wp_upload_dir['url'] . '/' . basename( $filename ),
                'post_mime_type' => $data['mime'],
                'post_type'     => $filetype['type'],
                'post_title' => preg_replace( '/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename( $filename ) ),
                'post_content'   => $data['content'],
                'post_status'    => 'inherit',
                'post_author' => $data['author']
      ),$filename);

    wp_get_attachment_image_src( $media, $size = 'thumbnail', $icon = false );
    $image = image_downsize( $media, $size );


    return apply_filters( 'wp_get_attachment_image_src', $image, $media, $size, $icon );
```

Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al usar la función wp_insert_attachment esta debe retorna el id del adjunto, use la función [is_wp_error](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_wp_error/) para verificar el error le esta devolviendo

```
$data = '';
if ( empty( $data['id'] ) ) {
    $data = $param->get_params();
    $filename = $data['file'];
    // Check the type of file. We'll use this as the 'post_mime_type'.
    $filetype = wp_check_filetype( basename( $filename ), null );
    // Get the path to the upload directory.
    $wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();

    $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment(array(
                'guid'           => $wp_upload_dir['url'] . '/' . basename( $filename ),
                'post_mime_type' => $data['mime'],
                'post_type'     => $filetype['type'],
                'post_title' => preg_replace( '/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename( $filename ) ),
                'post_content'   => $data['content'],
                'post_status'    => 'inherit',
                'post_author' => $data['author']
      ),$filename);

if (is_wp_error($attach_id)) {
echo $attach_id->get_error_message();
}else{
wp_get_attachment_image_src( $media, $size = 'thumbnail', $icon = false );
    $image = image_downsize( $media, $size );
}

    return apply_filters( 'wp_get_attachment_image_src', $image, $media, $size, $icon );
```

Answer (score 1):

Verifica que en la configuración de tu `php.ini` estas variables

```
upload_max_filesize = 10M    
post_max_size = 20M    
max_execution_time = 180
```

puede ser que la imagen que intentas subir supera el máximo que tiene por defecto